# Putting something at the very page border

Tags: margins, minipage, geometry

I want to push a minipage right at the left border of the page. I understood, that `\leftmargin` should be the distance between the page border and the text body. So using a negative `hspace` of that length should push it right to the edge. Yet it doesn't. Is there anything I'm missing?

Also, since the box' width is the same length, shouldn't it end flush with the text body?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, a4paper, nomarginpar, hoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{blackgray}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\hspace{-\leftmargin}%
\colorbox{blackgray}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\leftmargin}
                \color{white}test
        \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Output
[image: output]

Comment: Remember to extend your example to a full example, document class is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\leftmargin` is the wrong measure (helpfully...). The left margin is measured as 1 inch, plus the `\oddsidemargin` (which for an actual 2cm margin will be negative), so this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, a4paper, nomarginpar, hoffset=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{blackgray}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\hspace{-\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin\relax}%
\colorbox{blackgray}{%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin-2\fboxsep\relax}
                \color{white}test
        \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

Note the width setting for the `minipage`, which uses the same dimension, but also removes two lots of `\fboxsep` which is the padding around the text inside the `colorbox`.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the difference between `\leftmargin` and `\oddsidemargin`? What does the former consist of?
Also thanks for pointing out `\fboxsep`. I assume this spacing comes with the colorbox?

Comment: `\leftmargin` is used for indenting lists (and might better have been called `\listmargin` or similar...), `\oddsidemargin` is essentially what you want, except that there is this default `1in` applied to all margins. Yes, the `2\fboxsep` space comes from either side of the `\colorbox`, around the outside of the minipage.